# Spring data jpa error as antlr/RecognitionException] with root cause

Tags: spring-boot

[image]

while usign spring-data-jpa ,there is an exception reagrding antlr/RecognitionException .I have added antlr jar

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and with that information update your question.